# Isabelle - character and string literal support

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

How are character and string literals declared in Isabelle? I would like to use a character node value in the trie example of the Isabelle tutorial (declared as `'v option`).

```
datatype ('a,'v)trie = Trie "'v option" "('a * ('a,'v)trie)list"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `char` type, which represents 8-bit characters, and the `string` type, which is defined as a list of characters. There is also some syntax and pretty printing setup for character and string literals:

```
typ string
(* char list *)

term "''foobar''"
(* ''foobar'' :: char list *)

value "hd ''foobar''"
(* CHR ''f'' :: char *)
```

Note that string literals must be delimited with two single quotes `''`. Character literals must be entered as `CHR ''c''`. This currently works for most printable ASCII characters, but nothing above `0x7F`.

There are functions `nat_of_char` and `char_of_nat` to convert between these 8-bit characters and their ANSI codes (reprsented as `nat`).

There is also the type `String.literal`, which is essentially a type clone of `string` that hides the underlying list nature. This is mainly interesting for code generation, since target languages (e.g. Scala) might provide a dedicated string type (as opposed to just a list of characters). Conversion between `string` and `String.literal` is with `implode` and `explode`.

Note that if you want to export code using strings, you should probably import `~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Char.thy` to translate Isabelle's character type into the target language's character type. And even then, exporting code using `string` will result in code using lists of characters; you need to explicitly use `String.literal` in your Isabelle code equations in order to get the proper string type in SML, Scala and OCaml.

There are some thoughts about generalisation of Isabelle's character type to support multibyte characters, but that is still in the future.